# PHP-Rules Tutorial needed

Tags: php, rule-engine

Can any one provide a good link for a PHP-Rules  tutorial?

I can currently find only one:

- [Getting started with PHP Rules (by Greg Swindle; 07 Jan 2011)](http://swindle.net/php-rules/tutorials/getting-started)

But this link doesn't really mention how to use it in our application. And also, the example they have taken to explain doesn't have an output as such..

Comment: Can any one provide a good link for a PHP-Rules tutorial. He's looking for additional learning resources (which is not unreasonable, although it's not really a programming questions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some links:

- There is an older article on devx here: http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/42441
- a php5 port on github here: https://github.com/DerManoMann/phprules
- an api in phpdocs format is here: http://www.swindle.net/php-rules-sample/phpdocs/

There does not seem to be many tutorials on php-rules out there, but it should also be fairly straightforward in terms of use. If you have specific questions on code examples, you will probably get better answers and be able to move things forward.

Also, I'd recommend contacting the author, [Greg Swindle](http://www.linkedin.com/in/gregswindle), as he might be able to provide you additional tutorials.

Comment: that github port is AWESOME! It is a bit different from the original, so the official docs won't be 100% accurate, but it works like a charm  . Thanks for your answer. That helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I've put more than a few hours into rules engine, and finally got the crux working... This was not clear to me at all per the directions out there, so I figured this might help someone debating whether or not to use php rules.

**To get PHP rules out of codeigniter for simple and more controlled use**

Step 1: download the package from [The PHP Rules Download Page](http://www.swindle.net/php-rules/downloads)

Step 2: extract the archive, and copy the folder php-rules-sample/ system/ application/ libraries/ Phprules to somewhere on your php server.

Step 3:  De-codeigniter all of the files in the Phpules folder by commenting out the defined or die statement at the top of each file, and in Rule.php comment out the 3 lines that have a capital CI in them.

All files:
1:`<?php//if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');`

Rule.php:

```
//  private $CI;
    public function Rule( $name='' ) {
        //$this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->elements = array();
    }

    public function __construct( $name='' ) {
        //$this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->elements = array();
    }
```

Once this is all done, the following test.php will at least test out a rule and give you feedback.  (From the demo on the site):

```
<?php
include("/Phprules/Rule.php");

// Create the rule
$rule = new Rule('eligibleForGroupDiscount');

// Declare the minimun number of people required for discount
$rule->addVariable('minNumPeople', 6);

// Declare a "placeholder" variable for the actual number of people
$rule->addVariable('actualNumPeople', 0);

// Compare the two, i.e., 
// minNumPeople >= actualNumPeople
$rule->addOperator('GREATERTHANOREQUALTO');

// Create a RuleContext, i.e., a "Fact"
$ruleContext = new RuleContext('eligibleForGroupDiscountFact');

// Declare the minimun number of people required for discount
$ruleContext->addVariable('minNumPeople', 6);

// How many people are there?
$ruleContext->addVariable('actualNumPeople', 7);

// Evaluate
$result = $rule->evaluate($ruleContext);

// Print the resulting Proposition
echo $result->toString();

?>
```

This will at least get you to a place where you can start evaluating rules.  You can alter actualNumPeople to watch true and false toggle.